# Is "while" a preposition, an adverb or a conjunction in the example sentence?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

In the sentence:

> *I will watch **while** you sleep.*

I believe 'while' is an adverb because it is adding information to the verb 'watch' i.e. I'll be doing some action (watching), but the action would be happening while you're sleeping.

Am I thinking right?

Comment: A tip: first decide are you dealing with a simple or a complex sentence. If it is a complex sentence, then you can have an *adverbial clause* (a whole simple sentence) which is modifying the verb in the main clause. Subordinate (in this case adverbial) and the main clause are linked by a conjunction.

Answer (score 2):

No, [**while**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/while) as used is a conjunction:

> 2) during or throughout the time that   ⇒ "we waited while she dined"

It is joining two phrases, *I will watch* and *you sleep*. For example:

> I will watch the kids **while** you go to the store.

Answer (score 1):

*While* is not an adverb; it is the entire phrase headed by *while* which acts as an adverb.

In traditional grammar *while* is classified as a *subordinating conjunction*, because it joins a full declarative subordinate clause (*you sleep* in your example) to the main clause.

But the widely-followed *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston and Pullum, 2002) disputes this classification, arguing that it makes no sense to classify terms on the basis of the sort of complements they take. We do not reclassify verbs when they take clausal complements instead of nominal complements, or no complement at all. *CGEL* classifies *while* as a *preposition*:

> We therefore include in the preposition category all of the subordinating conjunctions of traditional grammar, with three exceptions. The exceptions are, first, *whether*; second, those occurrences of *if* that are equivalent to *whether* [...]; and, third, *that* when it introduces a subordinate clause. (*CGEL*, 600)